# ¿Cómo rellenar una celda de excel si tengo una ventana emergente?

Tags: html, excel, vba, macros

Tengo un código para enviar mensajes de whatsapp desde excel, todo el codigo funciona correctamente, lo que quiero es que en caso de que el número no tenga whatsapp, rellene una celda con "sin Whatsapp", este es el código HTML

```html
<div class="_1HX2v" data-animate-modal-popup="true"><div class="_3e9k9" data-animate-modal-body="true">
    <div class="_2fuxX">El número de teléfono compartido a través de la dirección URL es inválido</div>
        <div class="_2SGGH">
            <div role="button" tabindex="0" class="_30EVj gMRg5">
                <div class="_2jX3t _2rbZG dWI29 _1GbxC">
                    <div class="_2xUEC _2XHG4">OK</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Quisiera que en caso de aparecer esta línea de código se rellena una celda indicando "sin Whatsapp", gracias.

Este es codigo VBA que estoy usando, funciona bien para el envio de números que tienen el aplicativo instalado, sin embargo necesito hacer una especie de filtro para aquellos que no lo tienen.

```
Declare PtrSafe Function ShellExecute Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "ShellExecuteA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal lpOperation As String, ByVal lpFile As String, ByVal lpParameters As String, ByVal lpDirectory As String, ByVal nShowCmd As Long) As Long
Const SW_NORMAL = 1

Sub EnvioMasivo()

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim X
    Dim mensaje As String
    Dim UltimaFila As Long
    
    Let UltimaFila = Sheets("Hoja 1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    
    For Each rng In Sheets("Hoja 1").Range("A2:A" & UltimaFila)
        
        mensaje = VBA.Replace("whatsapp://send?phone=" & "57" & rng.Offset(0, 1).Value & "&text=" & _
        "Buen dia " & rng.Value & " Adjunto enviamos información correspondiente.", " ", "%20")
      
      'aqui necesito si el numero no tiene whatsapp me indique en la
      'fila y colunma de numero "SIN WHATSAPP"
      'Caso contrario si el numero si tiene whatsapp
      'continue el proceso
      
                
        X = ShellExecute(hwnd, "Open", mensaje, &O0, &O0, SW_NORMAL)
        
        Call SendKeys("~", True)
        Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:02")
        Call SendKeys("^v", True)
        Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:02")
        Call SendKeys("~", True)

        
    Next rng
    
      Sheets("Hoja 1").Select
    
       Application.ScreenUpdating = True
          MsgBox "Mensajes enviados con exito", vbInformation

      End Sub
```

Comment: Tu pregunta está etiquetada como VBA, así que por favor, pon el código que tienes desarrollado, qué errores te da, dónde estás atascado. Tu pregunta ahora mismo es imprecisa y demasiado amplia.

Comment: Hola, este es código que estoy usando, funciona bien para enviar mensajes a números que tienen el aplicativo, sin embargo lo que necesito es hacer un "filtro" que me indique que número no tienen el aplicativo.

Comment: *Quisiera que en caso de aparecer esta línea de código se rellena una celda indicando "sin Whatsapp", gracias.*... wow. Vienes, pones lo que tienes y nos pones lo que quieres... te has confundido totalmente, ***aquí no trabajamos para tí***. Haz algo, PERO HAZLO TÚ, y si tienes un error te podrán ayudar. Pero hacerlo por tí? No señor, si lo que buscas es alguien que trabaje por ti te recomiendo que vayas a alguna web de programadores freelance, hay muchas y están a rebosar de gente esperando que les manden trabajo :)

Comment: No he pedido que hagas el trabajo por mi, estoy pidiendo una guía de como podría hacerlo, agradezco tu recomendación talvez estas interesado en el trabajo???

Comment: Ahora has puesto el código en VBA. Ya es algo. Solo una duda: poner un valor en una celda es fácil, pero lo que no termino de ver en tu código es qué parte detecta si el número tiene o no whatsapp, es decir. ¿Qué valor devuelve tu código si no hay whatsapp? ¿Qué hace ahora mismo si lo ejecutas y ese número no tiene whatsapp? Pregunto esto para saber cómo atrapar ese valor en una variable y que lo devuelva a una celda

Comment: Es allí donde tengo el problema, no se como atrapar el código html, en caso de no tener whatsapp, por el momento en caso de no tener whatsapp no hace nada solo sigue con el siguiente número, te agradezco si me das una guía de como tal vez podria hacerlo.

Answer (score 0):

Mira a ver si esto es lo que buscas:

Muestra mensaje para celdas vacías y escribe en columna B "Sin Whatsapp" aunque lo lógico sería indicar "No procesado".
Se debería de poner más filtros para controlar el tipo de dato que envías. Longitud del numero de teléfono.. o demás controles que quieras poner en el IF, dependiendo de los requerimientos de la aplicación que envía los mensajes

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim X
Dim mensaje As String
Dim UltimaFila As Long
Dim NumIntentoenviosmasivos As Integer
Dim NumErroresenviosmasivos As Integer
    
Let UltimaFila = Sheets("Hoja1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row ' De ("Hoja 1") lo cambio a ("Hoja1")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False


For Each rng In Sheets("Hoja1").Range("A2:A" & UltimaFila) ' Hay un espacio en tu código entre Hoja y 1 que creo no es correcto
    
    mensaje = VBA.Replace("whatsapp://send?phone=" & "57" & rng.Offset(0, 1).Value & "&text=" & _
    "Buen dia " & rng.Value & " Adjunto enviamos información correspondiente.", " ", "%20")
  
   ' Control Celda Vacía
   If IsEmpty(c.Value) = True Then 'Aquí se deberían de poner mas controles por tipo: longitud, tipo de dato...Dependiendo de los datos de A2:A* y los requerimientos de la aplicación que envía los msn
                                    
      ' Ojo, los datos de la columna B serán sobreescritos en caso de error
      Sheets("Hoja1").Range("B" & c.Row & ":B" & c.Row).Value = "Sin Whatsapp"
      NumErroresenviosmasivos = NumErroresenviosmasivos + 1
      MsgBox "No se procesó la celda " & c.Address
      
   Else ' pasa el control
                
        NumIntentoenviosmasivos = NumIntentoenviosmasivos + 1
        X = ShellExecute(hwnd, "Open", mensaje, &O0, &O0, SW_NORMAL)
        
        Call SendKeys("~", True)
        Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:02")
        Call SendKeys("^v", True)
        Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:02")
        Call SendKeys("~", True)

   End If
   
Next rng

  Sheets("Hoja1").Select ' De ("Hoja 1") lo cambio a ("Hoja1")

   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
      MsgBox "Mensajes procesados con éxito: " & NumIntentoenviosmasivos, vbInformation
      MsgBox "Mensajes NO procesados: " & NumErroresenviosmasivos, vbCritical
```